# KDE becomes slow

Tags: process, hardware, process-management

I experience problems with KDE 4.11.1 on Arch Linux. It suddenly becomes laggy and unresponsive and just as suddenly returns to the normal state after some time.

Normal CPU load (KSysGuard):
[image: Normal CPU Load]

Current CPU Load:
[image: Current CPU Load]

There are no suspicious processes in the Process Table tab and even if I kill all processes not related to KDE or System, the situation does not change. CPU Load is shared between processes in the usual proportion: most of CPU is consumed by the application I interact.

How can I find the cause of this abnormal CPU consumption?

Comment: What makes you think it's CPU? Sounds more like a memory problem. Could you show us the output of `free` when KDE is lagging? Also, check `top`, that will tell you who is using the most CPU.

Comment: @terdon he probably thinks that because of the graph, which shows pretty high CPU utilization.

Comment: @jordanm yes but only one core at 100% which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Output of `free`: 
`Mem:       total 3998596    used 1815280    free 2183316          shared 0      buffers 98532     cached 842428
-/+ buffers/cache:     874320    3124276
Swap:            0          0          0`.
KSysGuard shows that memory consumption if 800 MiB/3.8 GiB.
If i run `top` I see the same results as in KSG Process table - the cpu gets grabbed by whatever is active, nothiing suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

> There are no suspicious processes in the Process Table tab and even if I kill all processes not related to KDE or System, the situation does not change.

So you are saying you have one CPU at 100% but no processes in the Process Table using that much?

Have a look next time in `top` or `htop` and see if they say the same thing.

If there's no process that can account for this, you may be experiencing hardware failure or a kernel bug.  Look int `/var/log/syslog` or where ever your higher priority messages are logged.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was completely hardware. Though at first I thought it to be software, because I installed Linux not a long time ago and *other operating system* was okay earlier.
The `sensors` command said that core temperature was around 80°C all the time system lagged, so I took a dryer and cleaned some dust from the cooler.